# Executing external commands

Tags: c, linux

I am attempting to make a program in C which presents a GUI and allows the user to select from a list of applications, which to install on the computer. I can manage the gui, but I've never been taught how to actually issue command line commands.
I know with bash its just `apt-get install firefox` for example, but how do I do such a thing with C? i.e. on click, the program runs 'apt-get install

The other problem is I'm not familiar with the proper name for this interaction, so it is hard to search.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the traditional C standard lib, you can choose from:

- `popen()` - Opens a process with stdio IO streams to read/write to the process
- `system()` - Executes a process with same IO streams as parent

or:

- `fork()` + `execl()` (or exec variants) which is essentially how `system()` is implemented.

Try the man pages on all of these.

Also, order "Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment" by W. Richard Stevens

Comment: Maybe you wanted a line break before 'system()...' ?

Comment: Thanks, all i was looking for is `system("sudo apt-get install <x>");`
I dont know why others seemed to think this was a hard task.

Comment: @Blackbinary: Because `system()` won't let the initiating process do much by way of keeping track of how the external command goes. If that's OK with you, good. If not there is `popen()`, and if that is not enough you'll find yourself deep in the unix internals: managing signals and IPC and and and...

Comment: @dmckee in this case, the user sees the terminal output of the command. So if there is any error, it is displayed. Thus system() is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could see how other people do it. Looks like you're trying to create something similar to [Synaptic](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/), you may check in their source.

Comment: not anything near as complicated. If anything I'd like to pipe commands to synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to (1) do command line parsing and (2) perform an installation of software. You should know that apt-get is a significant undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

The portable way to do this is with `system()`. The way that's less portable, but more flexible would be to use `fork()` followed by `exec()`. There is also popen,  if you need/want to communicate with the child via its `stdin` or `stdout` (e.g., if you want to capture its output and display it in a window).

Answer (score -1):

If using C is not a must, you can try coding in Python(Perl). You will greatly reduce development time, and you can use GUI modules like tkinter(Python) or Tk(Perl) etc that are easy to use. you will have your GUI up in no time.

Comment: using c and gtk+ the gui isn't the issue.